# What is an fstream object? An object to output to files and not actually the file stream or does it represent the file stream?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

fstream represents all the input and output file streams right? When I create an ofstream object, am I creating an object that can be used to output to files (doesn't actually represent the file stream) or am I creating a file stream? When I call the function `std::ofstream::open`, it creates the stream from the ofstream object to the file I specify right?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream 
description and usage examples. It is unusual to open the stream after creation rather than at creation.

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand the distinction you are making, what difference do you think it would make? But in any case I would answer no. The fstream object in your program is the file stream, and `std::ofstream::open` does **not** create any new objects. But it really is a matter of how you define your terms.

Answer (score 0):

"File stream" is a concept. You create a "stream" when you create an object of `std::ofstream` but it's not neccessarily associated with a file straight away. You can "associate" it either upon creation (by specifying the file as a constructor argument) or as a separate operation with use of `std::ofstream::open`

Comment: Oh, how about for cout? From what I understand and heard, stream is the data type that represents all output streams while cout is an object used to insert characters and numbers into the standard output stream. cout doesn't represent the standard output stream. Should fstream and it's objects be the same concept as iostream and cout?

Comment: @cppnoob. C++ is defined by the various C++ standards documents. Those documents don't talk about C++ constructs like objects and types 'representing' abstract concepts like streams. So if you're going to ask questions like this you need to define your terms because it's not clear (to me at least) what you are actually asking. And also bear in mind that what you have heard elsewhere might just be someone's possibly incorrect opinion. Maybe you have a more concrete question or doubt behind the question you are asking above. If so then I would ask that question instead.

Comment: @cppnoob `cout doesn't represent the standard output stream` - no. `std::cout` does exactly that, it **represents** the standard output stream. You might confuse the concepts of streams and their destinations. A stream is a mechanism which merely defines how the data reaches the stream's destination (whether it's a file, a string, or console output). In order for such a object to exist, the destination is not even required, but it would not make much sense without it